# How to override duplicate keys in Java Map

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have this as my query.

```sql
select a.cust_id,a.cust_name,b.cust_id,b.cust_name 
from acustomer a,bcustomer b
```

DaoImp using Spring NamedJdbcparameterTemplate

method:

```java
NamedJdbcparameterTemplate temp= new NJPT(datasource);
List<Map<String,Object>> out=temp.quertForList(query,parametermap);
```

But the problem is that whenever I get the output for this query in db tool, I get 4 columns but in program output I am only getting 2 columns, i.e `cust_id` and `cust_name` of a is getting overridden by `b` due to same key name in Map.

How can I fix this, please note the query will be different each time as I am using this method as a general one for my program and output will be a list of values, so cannot map any model class for the output.

Please note I want this function to be generic one which means the query will be changing each time and output will be of different types.

Comment: First I don't understand why you are using two table with same field

Comment: This should be a JOIN with aliases: `SELECT cust_id, a.cust_name AS a_name,b.cust_name AS b_name
from acustomer a JOIN bcustomer b USING (cust_id)`. You will only get 3 columns but that's all you need as the `cust_id` columns are equal. But why do you have two tables with the same columns? and why are the names different between the two tables?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne dont take the SQL statement it can be different each time, so if I have same field names and if I use the queryForList method the duplicate keys are getting ignored and data is coming incorrect.

Comment: @user3825800 If this isn't the real problem please post the real problem. And be assured that use of aliases is the solution. Whether your team or another team has to implement it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Well the easy solution would be to give your fields aliases, so that their keys would be different.

```sql
select a.cust_id a_cust_id, a.cust_name a_cust_name, b.cust_id b_cust_id, b.cust_name b_cust_name 
from acustomer a, bcustomer b 
where a.cust_id=b.cust_id
```

Then in the map you would find the aliases, `a_cust_id`, `a_cust_name`, `b_cust_id`, `b_cust_name`.

Comment: I know we can alias, but this is not done from my team, the query will be coming from a different team and we will just be executing it with this method. So is there any other way we can do this.

Comment: @user3825800 If you can't solve the problem within your team it is the other team that needs to ask the question. And get this answer.